# How do I get rid of .ready in my CS:GO server so I can start the server without 10 people

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm having issues starting my new server. I want to be able to start the match without having 10 people in the lobby. The server config that I am using is [Pug-set-up](https://github.com/splewis/csgo-pug-setup). I will also be very happy if someone could help me with how to put announcements in the chat where a message is being said like every 5 minutes or so like

> "This server is self funded to help or if interested donate monthy to become a VIP and earn reserved slots and more fun features"

Answer (score 1):

Just from browsing the code: Take a look at https://github.com/splewis/csgo-pug-setup/blob/master/scripting/pugsetup.sp, around line 600.

```
if (totalPlayers >= PugSetup_GetPugMaxPlayers()) {
  GiveReadyHints();
}

// beware: scary spaghetti code ahead
if ((readyPlayers == totalPlayers && readyPlayers >= 2 * g_PlayersPerTeam) ||
    g_ForceStartSignal) {
```

Since you said **you** want to be able to start the game, you can already do so via the 'force start' command `sm_forcestart`. By default this command is only allowed for users with `admin` permissions, but you can edit this in `permissions.cfg`.

Beware that if you let everyone do this it's highly likely you'll end up with every game being a 4 player game.

Answer (score 0):

In [this file](https://github.com/splewis/csgo-pug-setup/blob/master/configs/pugsetup/setupoptions.cfg), line 30, change the value of Team size to whatever you want. Note you need to double the value since you have two teams, so if you want a minimum of 6 players, you need Teamsize to be 3.

Messages being sent every X minutes are called Advertisements. One such advertisement plugin is available [here](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=155705).

Comment: thank you for helping, but i did what you said and i have no result. my goal is to make the game start after a 1:00 time frame of just one person joining. What settings should I alter to make this possible, to completely eliminate Readying as a whole?

Comment: You stated in your original question the goal was to allow starting the match without being forced to wait for 10 people to be present. If not even that is working, did you remember to restart SRCDS (so it loads the new configuration completely)?

Comment: As for your new question, eliminating Readying as a whole, as far as I can see, is impossible since team readying requires user input (which Sourcemod can't hook since it's serverside, not clientside.)